# Stopping User model from deleting an entry with signals

Tags: python, django-1.7, django-signals

I am looking for a way to use `Signals` to stop the `User model` from deleting an entry, so I would not have to rewrite the User model. Instead, I'm looking to edit a model. A BooleanField is already set up. This way I can keep user in the database, and still have a way to eliminate the user from searches based on this field. Basically, I want to have something to do the following:

1. Stop the deletion of the Instance
2. Change `Instance.userprofile.deleted_user` to `True`
3. Save `Instance.userprofile`

I know how to get 2 & 3 done. But I just can't find a way to accomplish step 1, that does not involve editing the Default User model.

the code I do have for the issue, but as stated in the comment I do not have a way to stop the delete.

```
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=User)
def user_delete_handler(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # stop delete then do the following
    instance.userprofile.deleted_user = True  # edit linked model to mark user as deleted
    instance.userprofile.save()  # save linked model
```

Comment: Do you have any code to show us?

Comment: @tokyovariable I do not have code for the issue in question, I have everything I need but stopping the deletion of the entry